# Could Giant Bats Fly with Giant Pterosaurs?

Tags: science-based, evolution, alternate-worlds, terraforming, ecology

Last year, the Adult Swim program *Primal* treated us to perhaps the most Halloweenish episode yet, "Terror Under the Blood Moon", in which our two unspoken protagonists--the caveman "Spear" and the tyrannosaur "Fang"--come across a flock of giant red bats.  The fact that this is the same world in which giant pterosaurs also live only amplifies the show's pulp fantasy atmosphere.

But what if this were in real life?

An Australian scientist had decided to terraform a recently discovered Earth-like planet with a more extensive list of organisms than Serina's:

- All 800 species of Australia's orchids
- All 57 species of Australia's palms
- All 3 species of Australia's southern beech
- All 75 species of Australia's mistletoes
- All 37 species of Australia's seagrasses
- All 39 species of Australia's mangroves
- All 69 species of Australia's cycads
- All 39 species of Australia's conifers
- All 390 species of Australia's ferns
- All 44 species of Australia's fern allies
- All 10-12k species of Australia's algae
- All 1,000 species of Australia's mosses
- All 800 species of Australia's horn/liverworts
- All 250,000 species of Australia's fungi
- All 3,238 species of Australia's lichens
- All the species of Australia's invertebrates
- All of Australia's prehistoric freshwater fish
- All of Australia's prehistoric amphibians
- All of Australia's prehistoric reptiles
- All 357 species of Australia's mammals (including the 76 species of bats)
- All of Australia's non-avian dinosaurs
- All the pterosaurs of the clade [Azhdarchoidea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azhdarchoidea)

In this long list, let's focus on only the two candidates--the bats and the pterosaurs.  Both groups had evolved from different ancestors yet looked similar to each other because they had similar problems.  In our timeline, bats evolved after pterosaurs, but putting the two groups in the same world will be the focus of the question.

Sooner than later, there will be a mass extinction that would drive away the biggest species.  In the case of the bats and the pterosaurs, only the smallest and most adaptable species will survive.  But this raises the question--**in a terraformed world without birds but still plentiful food, would both the surviving bats and pterosaurs fly the same skies, perhaps grow bigger to the extent presented in *Primal*?**

Comment: You really have a lot of unexplained (though perhaps irrelevant) background here, starting with WTF is "Primal".  However, the basic question seems to be whether bats and pterosaurs could coexist.  The answer seems an obvious yes, since bats and birds manage to do so.

Comment: In the current world, bats and flying dinosaurs coexist just fine. There are over 10,000 extant species of dinosaurs, most of them volant, a few secondarily flightless; and over 1,400 species of bats -- Chiroptera is the second largest order of mammals after Rodentia. Why would you believe that Chiroptera would find it so hard to coexist with Pterosauria when they don't seem to be bothered by Dinosauria?

Comment: @jamesqf  Yes, but could they grow bigger?

Comment: @AlexP  Yes, but could they grow bigger?

Comment: This is what the site calls a [high concept question](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4868/40609). High concept questions are off-topic because, without substantial inclusion of details, conditions, limitations, and requirements, the question is too broad and too opinion-based. As is the case here, the only valid answer is, "yes, if you want it that way." In short, the question is too speculative and lacks too much foundation information. Can you edit it to make it (a lot) less speculative?

Comment: @JBH High concept? Not so. It only takes a reading of previous comments to show the question is answerable. A basic understanding of ecology is all that is necessary. Plus knowing that resource rich environments animals become bigger. The question could be streamlined to be more to the point, but that's a trivial issue.

Comment: Establishing whether and why two experimentally amenable, extant species can or cannot co-exist involves hundreds (thousands?) of hours of field, lab, and theoretical work, and would constitute an award-winning and career-defining PhD thesis. Even then, it would be loaded with caveats and would be considered speculate and correlative.

Comment: Asking to do this with one set of species that are completely undefined (huge bats) and one that are known only indirectly (pterosaurs) is totally impossible and belies a fundamental misunderstanding about how ecology works, both in terms of our level of ignorance as humans but also inherent limits of the data. To suggest this is "basic ecology" is not only absurd, it's insulting to professional biologists!

Comment: @a4android I was unaware that high concept questions were intrinsically unanswerable. But a "basic understanding" of ecology? Surely you mean prehistoric ecology and the impact of crossing a modern ecology with it? It's tempting to look at the *Jurassic Park* franchise and assume that's a trivial relationship. But I'm pretty sure it's not. (And if the question of the creatures becoming bigger is considered central to the question, then it deserves to be closed as a duplicate. I haven't checked, but I suspect there's at least one other "how big can it get?" question out there.)

Comment: @JBH When I said a basic understanding of ecology it precisely that. This applies any ecosystem in general. The rest of your comment is sophistry. As for your suggested duplicate this shows you're misreading the nature of the question.

Comment: @AlexP: Reductio ad absurdum, or why can't all those variously evolved fish just swim in the sea together?

Comment: @a4android perhaps by "basic" you mean "naive". Come on guys, competitive exclusion does not play out at high taxonomic levels (hint: taxa above the species level doesn't really exist as biological entities). Large birds compete just as much with each other as they would with hypothetical large bats. To say that (some) bats could not become large because of the existence of some large birds (or pterosaurs) is to suggest that there should only be one large species of flyer around the entire globe.

Comment: @jamesqf: I don't understand.

Comment: @cereal_killer I mean "basic" & certainly not "naive". In the proposed environment bats would progressively fill all available ecological niches.Even the pterosaurs will do so too. The question is whether bats might develop gigantism if large pterosaurs are present.As you say, there are many large flyers on Earth this terraformed planet could easily be the same. Quite agree with you there.

Comment: @a4android Basic ecology really predicts that they would fill all the niches? Even in a fluctuating environment? If the species in question are subject to different evolutionary constraints? When mutualisms, antagonisms, and various other interactions are accounted for? When "niche space" is rugged instead of smooth? When stochastic extinction is a thing? Perhaps these things constitute "complex ecology", but then maybe basic ecology can't answer the posed question. The reality is that we barely understand this stuff in simple, modern systems, let alone in hypothetical ones.

Comment: @cereal_killer Not ecology, evolution. You should be congratulated on overthinking my comment (which was without all the qualifications it really need; many of which you have already covered in your response), & for jumping to wrong conclusions. By "all available ecological niches" I meant all those the bats could adapt to, subject to evolutionary pressures in the their environment. Complex systems are inherently unpredictable. Who would expect otherwise? Save your comments for the truly biologically challenged on this site, of whom there are many.

Comment: @AlexP: You claim that birds are dinosaurs.  By the same (absurd) logic, birds, dinosaurs, and mammals are all just fish.

Comment: @jamesqf: Birds actually look very much like maniraptoran dinosaurs and have similar life histories. And I'm in very good company; the current (= of the last quarter of a century or so) consensus understanding of Dinosauria includes both avian and non-avian forms. (Quoting Wikipedia: *"birds are a group of feathered theropod dinosaurs, and constitute the only living dinosaurs"*.)

Comment: Could you just please leave the spiders out of this project.

Comment: @CongenitalOptimist  Why?

Comment: @JohnWDailey Because ..tries to keep calm... wouldnt it be just nice?

Comment: @jamesqf fish is not a phylogenetically defined group, dinosaurs are. Dinosaurs are quite literally defined as the "the most recent common ancestor of triceratops and the common chicken and ALL of its descendants." there is no definition of dinosaurs that does not include birds. Birds are dinosaurs in the same way bats are mammals.

Comment: @John: In the same way that mammals are just a kind or reptile.  And certainly there is a definition of dinosaur that doesn't include birds, since birds evolved from (one type of) dinosaur) in the same way that mammals evolved from reptiles.

Comment: @jamesqf no reptile is a paraphyletic group, dinosaur is not. And there is no definition of dinosaur that does not include birds. This is a Dinosaur paleontologist telling you this. The closest you can get is non-avian dinosaurs which is like saying non-chiropteran Mammals. Birds are Dinosaurs in the same way bats or dogs are Mammals. Mammoths are not Dinosaurs, birds are Dinosaurs. There is not even an anatomical distinction for Aves.

Comment: @John: WRT "paraphyletic group", you are just creating a circular definition.  But the entire logic chain is faulty: it is saying that because some group of organisms are DESCENDED from some other group, they must always BE that group.  Birds and mammals and dinosaurs all had common ancestors, all the way back to LUCA. Other that that in certain circles, it has become "cool" to claim it, when any schoolkid can point out the difference?

Answer (score 2):

### Yes it is possible for them to coexist.

Birds and pterosaurs coexisted there is no reason bats and pterosaurs could not. In fact birds evolved while pterosaurs were dominant. The existence of fliers does not prevent the evolution of other flight. flying animals is to broad a category which group fits each individual niche is what matters and that is not a given.

Also consider Yi, a dinosaur with *Bat-like* wings. So not only did flight evolve in other groups while pterosaurs were around it happened *multiple times* reinforcing the idea that it is not an impediment.

[image]

### Now for size and ecology.

Bats with echolocation would certainly have a huge advantage at night so you may see a split along day/night. Or you may see a niche division, since bats have rotated hind legs, allowing attacking with the hind legs to evolve. live birth vs egg laying might favor one or the other in certain conditions. Hollow bones might provide a big advantage for size with pterosaurs so will likely see more large pterosaurs. Note pterosaurs were likely pushing the limit on the size for a flier in earths gravity so don't expect anything noticeably bigger.

Comment: I have misread.

Answer (score -1):

Pterosaurs are far more advanced flyers than bats. So they would have relations exactly as birds and bats has now: pterosaurs rule the sky and bats are "hiding" in some marginal niсhe.

If conditions would allow pterosaurs would [grow bigger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quetzalcoatlus).

But bats would have a chance to do it only in some isolated areas. And I doubt they would ever become as effective flyers as [ornithodira](https://fossil.fandom.com/wiki/Ornithodira) are. They just have no lots of very special improvements and couldn't have many of them. So any invasion of pterosaurs would shrink bats both in size and numbers.

Comment: "*Pterosaurs are far more advanced flyers than bats*" What is the basis for this claim?

Comment: Bats are not *"hiding"* anywhere. Bats are a very successful mammalian order, with over 1,400 species, ranging in size from the diminutive [*Craseonycteris thonglongyai*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kitti's_hog-nosed_bat) (wingspan 150 mm or 6 in, weight 2.5 g or 1/16 oz) to the megabat [*Acerodon jubatus*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Giant_golden-crowned_flying_fox) (wingspan 1.7 m or about 6 feet, weight 1.5 kg or 3 1⁄2 lb). They live all over the world and are very common. True, in most places they are much less common than birds, but they are in no way rare.

Comment: @DKNguyen, basis is hundred of millions years of pterosaur's evolution and millions of year of pterosaur coexistance with birds. Just read article in wikipedia - see how complex their wing was compared to bat's

Comment: @AlexP, bats are "hiding" - becase they are leaving in marginal hiches. Feeding mostly at night and keeping away from any birds spacial and/or time areas. And never ever try to "fight"(in any sense) with birds . Exactly like "successfull" mammals were living in dinosauros times. And btw, compare your bat's numbers with those of bird's. You will clearly see who is "hiding" from whom.

Comment: Bats are already better fliers than birds, with better performance (more lift, less drag, greater maneuverability, faster speed, more efficient). Birds have the advantage of a decoupled flight mechanism which makes them better at most everything not related to flight

Comment: @John, with good enough energy plant even brick would fly. Birds (an dinos as whole) are far more efficient in energy production and construction stability than mammals ever could be (just compare t-rex and elephant of same wight in terms of size and movement speed). Btw pterosaurs were even more flight-efficient than bats, but still lost the skies to birds. And you are quite wrong about speed. Fasterst living creatures on this planet (up to 200 km/h and above) were still insects and birds [last time I checked it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peregrine_falcon)

Comment: @ksbes thats not flying that is falling, by that measure a turtle is a faster flier than any of them, for actual flight bats win, Brazilian free-tailed bats may have achieved speeds of up to 160 kilometres per hour in level flight. also I need a source for efficiency in energy production and flight efficacy, mammals and birds use the same mechanism for energy production and we don't know how efficiency pterosaurs were since we can't measure their diet and O2 consumption. the difference between a t-rex and an elephant is about how well adapted their skeletons are to large size.

Comment: @ksbes also bird have been fliers for almost 100 million years longer, and yet bats still out preform them. the advantages birds have have nothing to do with their flight capabilities. also in total number bats and birds come out similar, birds have many more species which is what you expect form older evolution but bats have massive population sizes.